# Problems with PHP if

Tags: php, mysql

I can't get my PHP 'if' working as I want, this is the code I use

```
if ($loginselect = $mysqli->query("SELECT something FROM options WHERE type='anything'")) {
  $loginselect1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($loginselect);
  $loginselect2 = $loginselect1['something'];
  echo $loginselect2;

  if ($loginselect2 = '1') {
  ?>
    <h1>Title1</h1><hr>Text1
    </div>

  <?php
  }
  else {
  ?>
    <h1>Title2</h1><hr>Text2
    </div>
  <?php
  }
}
```

I echo the value $loginselect2 as you can see and it says 0, but it still echoes text 1 and not text 2. Is this an isue with PHP or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use `==` instead. A single `=` is assignment

Comment: `=` is assigning. `==` is evaluating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [comparing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) a variable with a value, you use `==` (or `===` if strict), not `=`.

So in your case, you want `if ($loginselect2 == '1') {`.

Answer (score 0):

You need two == signs for your if statement.

```
if ($loginselect2 == '1') {
?><h1>Title1</h1><hr>Text1
</div>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<h1>Title2</h1><hr>Text2
</div>
<?php
}
}
```